# Pattern-search for xml-comments

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, resharper

I´m using ReSharper 2019 and I am trying to search and replace some common code-smells in our solution. The one here is the following:

```
/// <summary>
/// OnCreate
/// </summary>
/// <param name="hook"></param>
public void OnCreate(object hook)
{
    ...
}
```

which is pure noise. Thus I created a custom search&replace-pattern in ReSharper:

[image]

Search-pattern:

```
/// <summary>
/// $name$
/// </summary>
/// $comments$
public $type$ $name$($args$)
{
    $statements$
}
```

Replace pattern:

```
/// <inheritdoc />
public $type$ $name$($args$)
{
    $statements$;
}
```

This should create the following:

```
/// <inheritdoc />
public void OnCreate(object hook)
{
    ...
}
```

but I get this instead:

```
/// <summary>
/// OnCreate
/// </summary>
/// <param name="hook"></param>
/// <inheritdoc />
public void OnCreate (object hook
    {
    })
    {
        ...
    }
```

Has anyone an idea if and how I can replace within xml-comments?

Comment: For the comments have you tired Identifier Placeholder with a regular expression?

Comment: @juharr I tried `\w*`, if you ment this.

Comment: I would think you'd need to also match the triple slash.  Basically a regex that matches multiple lines that start with white space then the triple slash and then whatever.

Comment: @juharr Huum? Why this? The pattern already is "3 slashes + $name$", where `$name$` is `\w*`. Why should I add the slashes to the name-identifier as well? Wouldn´t this result in 6 slashes?

Comment: I don't think you should have the slashes in the main pattern at all, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Also `\w` isn't going to match special characters.

Comment: @juharr You´re right about special characters. However I don´t mind for them. I guess I go with plain ASCII-characters.